# Can't click and drag on Sentelic FingerSensingPad on Vizio Ultrabook

Tags: synaptics, trackpad

I have a Sentelic FingerSensingPad on a Vizio CT15 Ultrabook. I am using kernel 3.9.

I am unable to click and drag (i.e. click with one finger, and move window around with the other.)

Setting the synaptic ClickPad=1 does not help. Adjusting the AreaBottomEdge does make a portion of the bottom of the clickpad unusable, but still I can not click and drag. It registers the click, but not the drag.

I paste below the output of xinput and synclient:

```
-> xinput list-props "FSPPS/2 Sentelic FingerSensingPad"
Device 'FSPPS/2 Sentelic FingerSensingPad':
Device Enabled (134):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (136): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (262): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (286):  38, 929, 38, 673
Synaptics Finger (287): 25, 30, 256
Synaptics Tap Time (288):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (289):   52
Synaptics Tap Durations (290):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (291):   1
Synaptics Tap FastTap (292):    0
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (293):  75
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (294):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (295):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (296): 24, 24
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (297): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (298):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (299): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.166667, 40.000000
Synaptics Edge Motion Pressure (300):   30, 160
Synaptics Edge Motion Speed (301):  1, 96
Synaptics Edge Motion Always (302): 0
Synaptics Off (303):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (304):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (305):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (306): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Click Action (307):   1, 1, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (308): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (309):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (310): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (311):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (312): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (313):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (314): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (315):        ... of unknown type CARDINAL
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (316): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (317):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (318):  1
Synaptics Gestures (319):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (320):   1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (321): 1, 1
Synaptics Area (322):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (323): 6, 6
Device Product ID (251):    2, 15
Device Node (252):  "/dev/input/event12"
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (581):  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

-> synclient
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 38
RightEdge               = 929
TopEdge                 = 38
BottomEdge              = 673
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
FingerPress             = 256
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 52
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
FastTaps                = 0
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 24
HorizScrollDelta        = 24
VertEdgeScroll          = 0
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.166667
TrackstickSpeed         = 40
EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 96
EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 6
VertHysteresis          = 6
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 0
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 0
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the function 'Drag lock' so you can select, drag to where you want (locked) and tap again to release the lock.
If that is what you want, you can run this command

```
synclient LockedDrags=1
```

But when you finalize the session you'll need to do it again. To persist I've put this command in `~/.bash_profile`. If the file doesn't exist, create it. There're other options out there but this works fine for me.

**New Edit:**

By the way, this is what my bash_profile looks like.

```
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient CircularScrolling=1
synclient CircScrollTrigger=3
synclient VertScrollDelta=-111
synclient HorizScrollDelta=-111
synclient LockedDrags=1
```

CircScrollTrigger=3, means I can start the 'Circular Scrolling' from area '3' (Right Edge) only. Delta=-111 invert the default direction. Value of '1' means enable for those properties.

**Review Edit:**

I noticed that there's a bug that overwrite the settings used above. After some research I found a solution that I copied here in case link go down.

Here’s how to make your custom touchpad configuration persistent through reboots and even suspends. Start by creating a file to hold your script. Run this command to create a touchpad_settings.sh file in your home directory and open it:

```
gedit ~/touchpad_settings.sh
```

Add your synclient commands to this file and save it. Mine looks like this:

```
synclient SingleTapTimeout=360 FastTaps=1
synclient TapButton2=2 TapButton3=3
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x ~/touchpad_settings.sh
```

Finally, set the dconf setting so GNOME knows where to find your script. Run the following command, but replace tom with your own username:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices hotplug-command "/home/tom/touchpad_settings.sh"
```

source: http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/11/06/persistent-touchpad-configuration-in-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: Hi Medeiros! How would one go about enabling this "Drag lock function"? Please expand your answer to include more information.

Comment: Hi @Alaa, you can run this command `synclient LockedDrags=1
`. But when you finalize the session you'll need to do it again. To persist I've put this command in ~/.bash_profile. There's others options out there but this works fine for me.

Comment: The LockedDrags works great. My original question wasn't about tap and drag, but about click and drag on a clickpad. Setting synclient ClickPad=1 doesn't seem to help. The tap and locked-drag function is very useful though! I didn't know this was an option.